# Python how to return a list to other functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, return

I have been trying to return the list so other functions can access it. But in all the other functions the variables become undefined. The command should be "return twitchClipLinks" right?

```
def api():
  #API via twitch to get the top clips of Just Chatting
  API_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/clips/top?game=Just%20Chatting&period=day&trending=false&limit=6'
  ID = 'REMOVED'
  auth = 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json'

  head = {
    'Client-ID' : ID,
    'Accept' : auth
  }

  r = requests.get(url = API_ENDPOINT, headers = head)

  twitchClipLinks = []
  data = r.json()

  for link in data['clips']:
    store = str(link['url'])
    twitchClipLinks.append(store)
  return twitchClipLinks
```

Comment: What do you mean by *the variables become unsolved*?

Comment: I got 5 other def that uses the twitchClipLinks. I get the error Undefined variable: 'twitchClipLinks'

Comment: Did u call this function from those functions? And did u assign the result to any variable? Inside every function, you have to add something like this: `twitchClipLinks = api()` Or you can define `twitchClipLinks` as a `global variable` and remove the `return` statement from ur `api()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside every function, you have to add something like this: `twitchClipLinks = api()` Or you can define `twitchClipLinks` as a `global variable` and remove the `return` statement from ur `api()` function.